# Data is not getting stored in the firestore after signup but auth is working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Can anyone tell why the information is not getting stored in the firestore, the credentials are reflecting in the authentication after signing up. I want those same details like username, email, and password used for signing up also to be stored in the firestore at the same time but the details I'm sending are not reflecting in the firestore. I'm inputting the data from the TextInput and setting them in the state.
Also, my firebase is in test mode so read and write are allowed in the firestore I created. I have imported the setting and config in the index file properly and auth is also working too

```
import {
  View,
  Text,
  Button,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  SafeAreaView,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
} from 'react-native';
import CustomTextInput from '../components/CustomTextInput';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';



const SignUp = (props) => {
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
  const [secondName, setSecondName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const registerUserNoThunk = async () => {
    const user = {firstName, secondName, email, password};

    try {
      const result = await firebase
        .auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password);
      // const data = await result.json();
      console.log(result);
      console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid, 'userid');
      const usersdata = await firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection('users')
        .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid,)
        .set({firstName, secondName, email});
      console.log(usersdata, 'usersdata');
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
        <KeyboardAvoidingView
          style={{flex: 1}}
          behavior="height"
          keyboardVerticalOffset="10">
          <View style={styles.mainview}>
            <View style={styles.card}>
              <CustomTextInput
                label="First Name"
                value={firstName}
                onChangeText={(text) => {
                  setFirstName(text);
                }}
              />
              <CustomTextInput
                label="Second Name"
                value={secondName}
                onChangeText={(text) => {
                  setSecondName(text);
                }}
              />
              <CustomTextInput
                label="Email"
                value={email}
                onChangeText={(text) => {
                  setEmail(text);
                }}
              />
              <CustomTextInput
                label="Password"
                value={password}
                onChangeText={(text) => {
                  setPassword(text);
                }}
                secureTextEntry
              />
              {/* <View>
                <Button title="Sign Up" onPress={registerUser} />
              </View> */}
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => {
                props.navigation.navigate('ScreenOne');
              }}>
              <View>
                <Text>Already a member? Login</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <View>
              <Button title="Sign Up" onPress={registerUserNoThunk} />
            </View>
          </View>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </>
  );
};

Custom Text Input File

import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, TextInput, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const CustomTextInput = (props) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.inputcontainer}>
      <Text>{props.label}</Text>
      <TextInput {...props} style={styles.inputstyle} />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  inputstyle: {
    borderBottomWidth: 2,
    borderBottomColor: 'grey',
    height: 30,
    padding: 0,
  },
  inputcontainer: {marginVertical: '5%', width: '100%'},
});

export default CustomTextInput;
```

Comment: is this just a syntax error in your question ```.doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid,)```? I'm seeing a comma after uid

Comment: what is it logging here? ```console.log(usersdata, 'usersdata');```

Comment: @AbdelP. there is no comma after uid when I run the code it is only by mistake

Comment: @AbdelP. userdata is the data which I'm trying to store in the firestore